# Как положить свойство объекта, в частности айдишку в ссылку?

Tags: html, css, ajax

```
function fillQuestionBlock(q) {
   let questionData =
       // вот здесь не могу положить айди, как ни крути
       '<a id="qTitle" href="'/questions/ + q.id'"> <h3 class="question-title mt-3">' + q.title + '</h3></a>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так, наверное?

```
'<a id="qTitle" href="/questions/' + q.id + '"> <h3 class="question-title mt-3">' + q.title + '</h3></a>'
```